# Set video/audio quality when recording using Command+Shift+5

Tags: audio, video

I'm using the combination of command+shift+5 to record both audio and screen video on my computer. The following drawing shows the excact configuration I'm using :

[image]

However, it seems like there's no option to set the quality and the default is probably the highest for my display which is `15.4-inch (2880 x 1800)` .

That's why I get huge files for each minute of recording and I basically working on code presentation so the visual quality is not that important.

Perhaps there's a way to reduce video quality, I couldn't find any (see attached snapshot - the `options` tab doesn't include this configuration)

Thanks !